# How to purge old directories programmatically in unix/shell?

Tags: unix

Does anyone have a good shell line for this?

I want to check the age on a directory. If I created multiple directories on a weekly basis and I want to purge them/delete them based on 7 days later for example.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will let you do a dry run, remove the `echo` if you like the output

```
find /path/to/toplevel -type d -mtime +7 -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

#### Update

If you have an older version of `find` that doesn't comply with POSIX 2004 then use this instead:

```
find /path/to/toplevel -type d -mtime +7 -exec echo rm -rf {} \;
```

or

```
find /path/to/toplevel -type d -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 echo rm -rf {}
```

The former terminated by `\;` will call `rm` for each directory it finds, the latter with `xargs` will attempt to call `rm` as few times as possible by passing multiple directories to a single call to `rm` and thus be much faster. The latter also has identical behavior to the first one terminated with a `+`

Comment: thank you, 3rd option works great. Can you elaborate on argument `-0`? thanks again.

Comment: @jdamae find's `-print0` and xargs's `-0` work in concert so that it doesn't get fouled up with file names that contain spaces, newlines, and other garbage characters by delimiting on a NUL character which the filesystem does not allow for filenames.  If you ever find yourself needing to use `-exec` on another more recent system, first try terminating with `+` and if that doesn't work use the `xargs` version.